# What is the excel formula to get an amount from one column if another column indicates a Y?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

What is the excel formula to get an amount from one column if another column indicates a Y?

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/if-HP005209118.aspx

Comment: If you want to do that for multiple cells then have a look at SUMIF, e.g. `=SUMIF(A:A,"y",B:B)`

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the [`IF`](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/if.php) [statement](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/if-HP005209118.aspx)?

```
IF( condition, [value_if_true], [value_if_false] )
```

Example:

[image]

```
=IF(B2="Y",C2,X)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you could just use an `If` function...

Supposing your "Y" column is column A and you want to get the data from column, say, C, your formula could be:

```
=If(A1 = "Y", C1, "")
```

This will either return the value from column C or be a blank cell...

Answer (score 0):

Here's the formula if the column with your Y's and N's is column A, the amounts are in column B, and we're working with row 1:

```
=IF(A1="Y",B1,0)
```